# Boostrap 4 accordion несколько штук

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

у меня есть таблица в виде аккордиона

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при нажатии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача состоит что на сайте будут штук 20

я к примеру добавил скрипт jQuery

```js
$(function() {


  $('#tableColor').click(function() {
    $('#tableColor').toggleClass('collapsed ActiveClass');
  });







});
```

```html
<div class="zakaz-table">
  <table>
    <thead data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table1" id="tableColor">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"><span>01</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span>Трубы</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span>длина хлыста</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span>метров в пачке</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span>количество пачек</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span>итого метров</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="collapse" id="table1" aria-expanded="false">
      <tr>
        <td data-label="01">000020022</td>
        <td data-label="Трубы">PPR Труба PN10 D110 КОНТУР</td>
        <td data-label="длина хлыста">04/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="метров в пачке">04/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="количество пачек">2</td>
        <td data-label="итого метров">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row" data-label="01">000020022</td>
        <td data-label="Трубы">PPR Труба PN10 D20 КОНТУР</td>
        <td data-label="длина хлыста">03/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="метров в пачке">$2,443</td>
        <td data-label="количество пачек">3</td>
        <td data-label="итого метров">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row" data-label="01">000020022</td>
        <td data-label="Трубы">PPR Труба PN10 D25 КОНТУР</td>
        <td data-label="длина хлыста">03/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="метров в пачке">$1,181</td>
        <td data-label="количество пачек">количество бухт</td>
        <td data-label="итого метров">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Подкиньте идею как сделать правильно.**

Comment: $('.collapse').collapse() зачем переключать класс и что-то такое делать?

Comment: помимо id можно и классы использовать

Comment: что то вроде такого должно у вас быть `$(this).siblings("tbody").collapse('toggle')` для `$('thead').click(...)`